# How can blockchain send my all money without any notification??

Tags: blockchain

Yesterday  I made deposit  in blockchain wallet and  after that next morning  when i chk my Wallet  all bitcoin  were sent to an address  even i didn't made any transaction  how can any one tell me and this was my first  transaction  in blockchain can anyone know jow to recover  my fund

Comment: Did you have 2FA enabled?

Comment: Yes i have enabled